# Inexplicably High Load

Tags: performance, catalina, macos

I am finding that even as soon as a boot my MacBook Pro running Catalina up fresh (even after an SMC reset) the load levels can immediately spike to insane levels (like over 100+) and will hover between 30 and 50 while the handful of my startup apps complete their initiation. (Google Backup Sync is the worst as it will hog a CPU for at least 5 minutes just to confirm that there is nothing needing update.) Even as these tasks complete and use an entire CPU to do their thing, it's not like the machine is crippled in the interim.

While it would certainly be natural that a machine starting up would have high load, watching processes and system resources in htop and iostat, it would seem that my dual core 3.1 GHz CPUs are averaging around 50-60% usage, my 16 GB of RAM isn't even up for caching yet, and there is 0 paging going on and memory pressure that never gets about 18-20% at all times. There is zero IOWait. All CPU is either system or user. By any normal standard my machine (even if one CPU is pegged) is not even close to being overloaded.
I temperature seems like the first culprit, I watch CPU temperature obsessively and have my own fan rules to keep things especially cool. While processor speeds fluctuate (a feature of the i7 chipset) the speed will pop up to 3.4 GHz for a short while if it's needed.

Still, these crazy load spikes seem to defy the load index as a metric. For what is effectively a 4 CPU machine, a load of 4 would be "perfect efficiency" where there is theoretically no blocking. However, if I was on a Linux host and I saw a load of 100+ even for a few seconds, I probably wouldn't even be able to type anything as there would have to be some serious blocking and queuing going on. While things get a mite sluggish it's nothing like that or even what it's like when a machine starts to overheat. My inclination is that the load metric on MacOS is meaningless and I should ignore it, but that feels like a total cop-out. Does anyone else have a better answer for this?

Comment: "a load of 100+" … where are you seeing this? If Activity monitor, the top section shows usage per core [inc HT], not per CPU, so 100% is 1/8th the total load for a 4-core CPU with HT.

Comment: @tetsujin This is what `htop` would report.

Comment: Double-check in Activity Monitor, but as far as I'm aware, htop reports per core too.